# Processing code- Touch screen eraser code

Tags: java, processing, multi-touch

I was steered over to this forum when I asked my lecturer for advice on a piece of code for a group project. The general idea is that there are two images on top of each other, the user can wipe the top image away to reveal the one underneath.

Using some other projects from this forum, I have managed to get the basics running, however I am struggling to get the code to the starting point once the user lets go of the mouse.

I would also appreciate any advice regarding how to convert this to using a touch screen. I have looked at the multitouch code within the processing app, however it does not allow me to add images to this, and if I try and use the computer software it does not seem to like the multitouch. Is there any way around this?

The code I currently have is below, I will be greatful so any advice or input- thanks in advance!

```
PImage img, front;
int xstart, ystart, xend, yend;
int ray;

void setup()
{
    size(961, 534);
    img = loadImage("back.jpg");
    front = loadImage("front.jpg");
    xstart = 0;
    ystart = 0;
    xend = img.width;
    yend = img.height;
    ray = 50;
}

void draw() 
{
    {
        img.loadPixels();
        front.loadPixels();

        // loop over image pixels 
        for (int x = xstart; x < xend; x++)
        {
            for (int y = ystart; y < yend; y++ )
            {
                int loc = x + y*img.width;
                float dd = dist(mouseX, mouseY, x, y);        
                // pixels distance less than ray  

                if (mousePressed && dd < 50)
                {
                    // set equal pixel
                    front.pixels[loc] = img.pixels[loc];
                }
                else
                {
                    if (!mousePressed)
                    {
                      // reset- this is what I have not been able to work as of yet
                      front.pixels[loc] =   ;

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        img.updatePixels();
        front.updatePixels();
        // show front image
        image(front, 0, 0);
    }    
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but right now it's not very clear what you're asking. Can you please try to [break your problem down into smaller steps](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/how-to/program)? Which line of code is behaving differently from what you expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to use a [mask](https://processing.org/reference/PImage_mask_.html) instead of changing the pixels of the image. Create an empty image and associated it as mask to the the image:

```java
img = loadImage("back.jpg");
front = loadImage("front.jpg");
mask = createImage(img.width, img.height, RGB);
img.mask(mask);
```

If you now draw both images, then you can only "see" the `front` image:

```java
image(front, 0, 0);
image(img, 0, 0);
```

Set the color of the mask (255, 255, 255) instead of changing the pixel of `front`:

```java
mask.pixels[loc] = color(255, 255, 255);
```

and reapply the mask to the image

```java
img.mask(mask);
```

When the mouse button is released, the pixels of the mask have to be changed back to (0, 0, 0) or simply create a new and empty mask:

```java
mask = createImage(img.width, img.height, RGB);
```

See the example where I applied the suggestions to your original code:

```java
PImage img, front, mask;
int xstart, ystart, xend, yend;
int ray;

void setup() {
    size(961, 534);

    img = loadImage("back.jpg");
    front = loadImage("front.jpg");
    mask = createImage(img.width, img.height, RGB);
    img.mask(mask);

    xstart = 0;
    ystart = 0;
    xend = img.width;
    yend = img.height;
    ray = 50;
}

void draw() {
    img.loadPixels();
    front.loadPixels();

    // loop over image pixels 
    for (int x = xstart; x < xend; x++) {
        for (int y = ystart; y < yend; y++ ) {
            int loc = x + y*img.width;
            float dd = dist(mouseX, mouseY, x, y);        

            if (mousePressed && dd < 50) {
                mask.pixels[loc] = color(255, 255, 255);
            }
            else {
                if (!mousePressed) {
                    //mask = createImage(img.width, img.height, RGB);
                    mask.pixels[loc] = color(0, 0, 0);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    mask.updatePixels();
    img.mask(mask);

    // show front image
    image(front, 0, 0);
    image(img, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I had not thought of this option, however when I implement the code with the tweaks you have suggested, I am getting a solid grey screen- any ideas why this could be happening? Grateful for all of your help!

Comment: @elp37 Of course I've tested the code which I've posted. All you've to do is copy/paste.

Comment: I have copied and pasted the code above over however it is still displaying as a plain grey screen- any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: @elp37 No I've idea. I just tried the code of my answer again (copy/past) and it works fine. Of course my images are different to yours. But is probably not the issue. Are the textures proper located at your system?

Comment: Hmm weird- the images are in the right place so I will have to look into it- thanks for your help!

Comment: @Rabbid76- I have managed to get it to work by altering the line inside (!mousepressed) to  mask.pixels[loc] = color(0, 0, 0); - Thank you so much for all of your help!